# Should I declare new statefulwidget again and again to make new pages?

Tags: listview, flutter

I know my question is not easy to understand. But I don't know how I explain this problem, since I'm a totally beginner who don't know how much I know.
I want to make a ListView with 5 list tiles. When I press each list tile, it makes me go to new page. And each page has different items but its frame is totally same. For example, let's say there are 10 list tiles named tiger, lion, pig, horse, and dog. When we press 'tiger tile', we go to the tiger page(with navigator.push). In that page, we can see image of tiger(Image), and explanation of tiger(Text). And when we press 'lion tile', we may go to the lion page, and it let us see its picture and explanation.

I think programming is the way to remove any unnecessary work. So I believe there is some way to solve this problem. So I googled it, and found it in stackoverflow, but I couldn't. That's probably because of lack of my English, or programming.

`enter code here`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        home: HomePage()
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Animal List'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Lion'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => LionPage()), );
              }
            ),
            ListTile(
                title: Text('Tiger'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return TigerPage();
                          }
                      ));
                }
            ),
            ListTile(
                title: Text('Horse'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return HorsePage();
                          }
                      ));
                }
            ),
            ListTile(
                title: Text('Pig'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return PigPage();
                          }
                      ));
                }
            ),
            ListTile(
                title: Text('Dog'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return DogPage();
                          }
                      ));
                }
            ),

      ),
    );
  }
}

class LionPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LionPageState createState() => _LionPageState();
}

class _LionPageState extends State<LionPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Lion'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
              height:200.0,
              width: 200.0,
              child: Image.asset('lion.jpg', )),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),),
          Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Text('It is a lion.',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
              )
            ],
      )]
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TigerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TigerPageState createState() => _TigerPageState();
}

class _TigerPageState extends State<TigerPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Tiger'),
      ),
      body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
                height:200.0,
                width: 200.0,
                child: Image.asset('tiger.jpg', )),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),),
            Wrap(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Text('It is a tiger.',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
                )
              ],
            )]
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HorsePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HorsePageState createState() => _HorsePageState();
}

class _HorsePageState extends State<HorsePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Horse'),
      ),
      body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
                height:200.0,
                width: 200.0,
                child: Image.asset('horse.jpg', )),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),),
            Wrap(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Text('It is a horse.',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
                )
              ],
            )]
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PigPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PigPageState createState() => _PigPageState();
}

class _PigPageState extends State<PigPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Pig'),
      ),
      body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
                height:200.0,
                width: 200.0,
                child: Image.asset('pig.jpg', )),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),),
            Wrap(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Text('It is a pig.',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
                )
              ],
            )]
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DogPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DogPageState createState() => _DogPageState();
}

class _DogPageState extends State<DogPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Dog'),
      ),
      body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
                height:200.0,
                width: 200.0,
                child: Image.asset('dog.jpg', )),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),),
            Wrap(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Text('It is a dog.',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
                )
              ],
            )]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With this code, I must make each of 5 codes similar to themselves.
But if it is possible to declare any method like "MakeAnimalPage()", I can write in easier and simpler way like "MakeAnimalPage(lion)".
Is there any way like declaring method?

Comment: see [ListView.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) and point `2.` in the official [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) documentation

Comment: Could you tell me more specific? Actually I don't know how to see Listview.builder

Comment: what is not specific? did you see the point `2.`? if so, whats unclear? [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html#widgets.ListView.2) you have some code samples - just read the official documentation

Comment: Oh, dear, I think I got a clue. Thank you very much. But don't think of me as lazy person. I really tried sincerely. Thank you! Hope you have a nice weekend!

Comment: sure, your welcome, have a nice weekend too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can check this code, i have totally changed your code as per your requirement.](https://github.com/hardik584/Flutter-lunchbox/blob/master/Jinsub_Kim.dart)

If you still fill confused then comment here!!!

Comment: Perfect! When I try and meet some error, I'll check your suggestion. Thanks to all of you, it became my best day. Thank you so much. I hope you guys get lucky, too.